# Remove all words from string which have letters from another string(1 word)

Tags: c, string, char

My program removes only letters.
But I need to remove the words in "str2" that consists letters from "str1".
How should I do that? please write the code
my program is:

```
char str1[size], str2[size], newstr[size];
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;


printf("Enter the test word:\n");
gets(str1);

printf("Enter the string:\n");
gets(str2);

for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; str2[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == str2[j])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            
            newstr[k] = str2[j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    newstr[k] = '\0';
    strcpy(str2, newstr);
    k = 0;
    
}
    printf("New string: %s\n", newstr);
            
return 0;
}
```

I think strtok, strpbrk can help but unfortunately I dont understand how to use it.
I tried only to use strok to break string into pieces.

Comment: When you say `words in "str2" that consists letters from "str1"` do you mean `words in "str2" that consist COMPLETELY of letters from "str1"` or `words in "str2" that contain ANY letters from "str1"`

Comment: If you are trying to do things with words you need to  loop through looking for spaces and punctuation.  You could use strtok() with space as delimiter but then you have to go back and replace the inserted \0 with spaces.  strcspn() and strpbrk() are for finding multiple things so you could use then for finding spaces and punctuation but you will need a loop anyway so you might was well just use a loop with an if statement.